# Pass an Object from a component to another using routes

Tags: angular

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 and I have in a page a list of news. I have a button called "See details" and I want to take the user to another page (component) to show all the information.

```
    // Object to pass
    News {
      title: string;
      date: Date;
      body: string;
    }

    // Routing
    {path: 'news-details/:data', component: NewsDetailsComponent},

    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of newsFromToday; index as i">
         <button type="button" [routerLink]="['/news-details', data]">See details</button>
    </ng-container>
```

In the component that I want to receive the data:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        const data = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('data');
        console.log(data);
      }
```

> Page not found

I have tried:

```
<button type="button" routerLink="/news-details/{{JSON.stringify(data)}}">See details</button>

ngOnInit() {
    const competitionData = JSON.parse(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('data'));
    console.log(competitionData);
  }
```

> read property 'stringify' of undefined at Object.eval [as
>   updateDirectives]

My goal is to receive the Object in a variable to show all the information in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with ActiveRoute (if you want pass object by route - use JSON.stringfy/JSON.parse):

```
// Routing
{path: 'news-details', component: NewsDetailsComponent}


<ng-container *ngFor="let data of newsFromToday; index as i">
     <button type="button" (click)="showNewsDetails(data)">See details</button>
</ng-container>
```

Prepare object before sending:

```
constructor( private router : Router) { }

showNewsDetails(data) {

  let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
        "data": JSON.stringify(data)
    }
  };

  this.router.navigate(["news-details"],  navigationExtras);
}
```

Receive your object in destination component:

```
 constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    super.ngOnInit();

  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     const data = = JSON.parse(params["data"]);
  });
}
```

**note that** if you do not want to expose all data in the URL, using a service is the way to go. In route params you should only pass data that you want to be reflected in the browser URL bar.

Comment: Hi, I receives the same error, Page not found. All the data is in the browser URL bar by the way. Maybe I should use a service and just send the ID of the news to the component?

Comment: make sure the route is *path: 'news-details'* without *:id* parameter, so it can match it.

Comment: Service solution is recommended, because query strings aren't supposed to carry complex data, and I see no urgent need for it here.

Comment: It works, maybe you should indicate that detail about the routing path in your answer for future users.

Comment: :D I wrote it at the beginning of my answer under //routing comment.
Glad that it helped you.